# How would I verify that unused NIC's in a Windows Server are disabled?

Tags: vbscript, wmi

I need to check a Windows Server (many of them a day) and just verify that Unused NIC's are disabled. This is just one of many checks I'm doing.

I'm trying to figure out how I can do this and this is my following code.
It gives me an error with objNetwork.PhysicalAdapter saying

> Object doesn't support this property or method:
>   'objNetwork.PhysicalAdapter'

```
Sub CheckUnusedNICs()
   WScript.Echo("Check for unused NICs")
   WScript.Echo("------------------------------------")
   Set colNetwork = objWMISrvc.ExecQuery("SELECT * from Win32_NetworkAdapter")
   For each objNetwork in colNetwork
      WScript.Echo objNetwork.AdapterTypeID & vbCrLf
      WScript.Echo objNetwork.PhysicalAdapter
     'If (objNetwork.AdapterTypeID = 0 AND objNetwork.PhysicalAdapter = True) Then
    '    WScript.Echo("Placeholder")
     ' End If
   Next
End Sub
```

I'm by no means proficient in VBScript but I'm learning it as I go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WMI `Win32_NetworkAdapter` class doesn't have a `PhysicalAdapter` property.

Use `NetConnectionStatus` and `ConfigManagerErrorCode` properties instead.

A device would be:

- Enabled and connected if:
  `NetConnectionStatus = 2`
- Enabled and no cable is plugged in if:
  `NetConnectionStatus = 7`
- Disconnected due to disabled device if:
  `(NetConnectionStatus = 0) and (ConfigManagerErrorCode = 22)`

More details about `Win32_NetworkAdapter` class including the full list of the above codes can be found at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394216(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thank you. I didn't see that "PhysicalAdapter" property was deprecated.